# How to change ordering in the list of figures and how to change the style of title of list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents

I guess my problem is pretty basic one but since I am new to the Latex I could not manage to solve it. I want the title of "List of Figures" in italic. And in the list of figures instead of using numbers for figures, I want to use figure number itself like Figure1, Figure2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass...
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Large\itshape} % italic LoF title
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em} % space for Figure and number; change to suit
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure} % put Figure before number
```

Read the manual (`texdoc tocloft`) and make any appropriate adjustments to the above code.